# Getting value of web php.ini file from console script

Tags: php, laravel

As we know for web and console, different PHP ini files are used. For example if I run `ini_get('max_execution_time')` from console script, it would return `0` because console scripts generally don't have timeout. But if I run same code from web, it will return a value that we have set for our website instead.

I want to run below code from console script:

`ini_get('max_execution_time')`

However this would return me value as `0` because PHP uses different php.ini file for console. What I want is when I run above code, I want it to return value of what would be set from php.ini that is supposed to be for web NOT console.

The reason why I need value of web php.ini for different values is because I am building console script that would check for values and notify me via email if any php.ini setting is not right for web application.

FYI, I am using Laravel framework.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `echo php_ini_loaded_file();` from the web to find the name of the *web/apache2* ini file. In my case, it is */usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini*.

Then, in your CLI application, you can parse the ini file into an array which you can use to retrieve the data you need.

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('/usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini');

// Ouput of `var_dump($config);`
array (size=118)
  'engine' => string '1' (length=1)
  'short_open_tag' => string '1' (length=1)
  'precision' => string '14' (length=2)
  'output_buffering' => string '4096' (length=4)
  'zlib.output_compression' => string '' (length=0)
  'implicit_flush' => string '' (length=0)
  'unserialize_callback_func' => string '' (length=0)
  'serialize_precision' => string '-1' (length=2)
  'disable_functions' => string '' (length=0)
  'disable_classes' => string '' (length=0)
  'realpath_cache_size' => string '256k' (length=4)
  'zend.enable_gc' => string '1' (length=1)
  'expose_php' => string '1' (length=1)
  'max_execution_time' => string '500' (length=3)
  'max_input_time' => string '60' (length=2)
  'memory_limit' => string '256M' (length=4)
  'error_reporting' => string '32767' (length=5)
  'display_errors' => string '1' (length=1)
  'display_startup_errors' => string '1' (length=1)
  ...

echo $config['max_execution_time']; // 500
```